# Reload data of a UITableView Inside another viewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I'm working on a little new project/game in Swift/Storyboards but I came across this little obstacle... The game consists of 2 navigation viewcontrollers and on the first view controller I wanted to add a menu-esque view where the person can add players (more precisely their names) that want to play with him and that the names then show up inside a tableview as seen in the screenshot I added.

I managed to get it working the first time when you enter a name and press "+", playerArray gets appended with the input BUT the tableview does not update at all, and after pressing "+" for a second time I get an error:

" Thread 1: "attempt to insert row 2 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update" "

I'm completely new to tableviews so I don't really know how to solve this even after searching the internet

My code for the view controller (Don't mind print statements just to check until where the code did what it had to do):

```
class Home_ViewController: UIViewController {
    // Parameters and start values
    
    var game_mode:Int = 1
    let storage = UserDefaults.standard
    var tableviewcontroller = player_table_Controller()
    
    @IBOutlet public var NewPlayerOutlet: UITextField!
    
    // Load view
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Navigation stuff ---->
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(systemName: "arrowshape.turn.up.backward.fill")
        // Leave this be <----
    }
    
    //Dismiss keyboard after editing textfield
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        view.endEditing(true)
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
        backItem.title = "   "
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem // This will show in the next view controller being pushed
    }
    
    // View appears back
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }
    
    @IBAction func add_player(_ sender: Any){
        print("Function add player called")
        
        if NewPlayerOutlet.text == nil || NewPlayerOutlet.text == "" {

                print("No name entered")

            } else {
                let newPlayer = NewPlayerOutlet.text!
                tableviewcontroller.PlayerArray.append(newPlayer)
                print("New Player: ", newPlayer)
                print(tableviewcontroller.PlayerArray)
                
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: tableviewcontroller.numberOfRows(inSection: 0), section: 0)
                tableviewcontroller.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                
                tableviewcontroller.reloadData()

            }
        
    }
}
```

and the code for the table view and cell:

```
class player_table_cell: UITableViewCell{
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var NameLable: UILabel!
    
    @IBAction func removePlayer (_ sender: Any){
        
    }
    
}

class player_table_Controller: UITableView{
    
    public var PlayerArray:Array = [String]()

    override func numberOfRows(inSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return PlayerArray.count
    }
    override func cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell? {
        let cell = self.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! player_table_cell
        let Player = PlayerArray[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.NameLable.text = Player
        print("This is called and known players are:", PlayerArray, "and current used is", Player)
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

[screenshot of the primary viewcontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRgpY.png)

Comment: This is a very common mistake. `player_table_Controller()` – by the way please name structs/classes *UpperCamelCase* and variables/functions *lowerCamelCase* – creates a brand new instance of the controller which is not the instance in the storyboard. You need the real instance with a segue or instantiation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing my mistake out! After some tweaking and integrating the tableview into my Home class I got everything to work! Also, I know I'm a bit of a mess I learned to code with "_" a few years ago and now I'm doing both combined which really makes a mess out of it, I'll keep an extra eye out!

Comment: The underscore characters are fine in PHP or Javascript but are discouraged in Swift.